# I can't get my wildcard certificate to work

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, web

I'm running Apache v `2.4.38` on Debian 10 `4.19.0-11-cloud` (amd64), and I can't my wildcard certificate to work

Steps I done (all as root) :

- Issued a Let's Encrypt certificate using [acme.sh](https://acme.sh)

```bsh
acme.sh --issue --apache -d example.com -d '*.example.com' --dns dns_cf
```

- Ran `acme.sh --list` :

```
Main_Domain  KeyLength  SAN_Domains      CA               Created                          Renew
example.com   ""        '*.example.com'  LetsEncrypt.org  Thu 22 Oct 2020 11:35:09 AM UTC  xxxx
```

- Installed it on my Apache installation :

```bsh
acme.sh --install-cert -d example.com \
--cert-file /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-cert.pem \
--key-file /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-key.pem \
--fullchain-file /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/letsencrypt.pem \
--reloadcmd "systemctl force-reload apache2"
```

- And appended my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-key.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/letsencrypt.pem"

SSLCACertificatePath "/etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/"
SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/letsencrypt.pem"
```

And If I try to connect using https I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on Chrome and by `Secure Connection failed` on Firefox

I tried :

- Checking the access and error logs, no errors whatsoever
- Disabling and enabling mod_ssl using

```
a2dismod ssl && a2enmod ssl
```

- Modifying `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` to reflect the new certificates

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-key.pem
```

- Disabling ufw

```
ufw disable
```

- Tried reissuing the cert
- Tried reinstall of all the LAMP stack
- Checked that my hosting company doesn't block port 443 on the firewall, which isn't the case

I block here, I can't find a way to make it work

Comment: Maybe you should put the SSLCertificateFile lines inside the `VirtualHost`, as shown [here](https://comodosslstore.com/resources/how-to-install-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-on-apache/), where you should also add `SSLEngine on`.

Answer (score 0):

1- Check apache is listening on 443 /etc/apache2/2.2/ports.conf :

Listen 443

2- Wrap your current configuration within a Virtual Host :

```
<VirtualHost *:443> 
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot <path-public-root>
SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-cert.pem 

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/wildcard-key.pem 

SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/letsencrypt.pem"

SSLCACertificatePath "/etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/" 

SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/apache2/2.2/ssl/letsencrypt.pem"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_ssl.log LogLevel warn 
 </VirtualHost>
```

3- Check and validate your certificates since your website is online with [DigiCert](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.digicert.com/help/&ved=2ahUKEwip6tDXqsnsAhWQlxQKHWt3CF0QFjAJegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw1UpsgyS4C7YdDTdmYjXb6t)

4- Query your Endpoint :

```
openssl s_client -connect example:443
```